# Intellij Debugger doesn't stop at conditional breakpoint

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints

When I put my conditional breakpoint in this loop

```
for(Site site :sites)
{
    //something
    //something
    //conditional breakpoint here
    //something
}
```

with the condition `site.getCode().equals("1234");`

I have the message:

```
Problem processing VM event:
Breakpoint: Error: Failed to evaluate breakpoint condition
'site.getCode().equals("1234")'
Reason: Cannot find local variable 'site'
Would you like to stop at the breakpoint?
```

Can somebody help me to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: stop at the breakpoint and see you local variables, is "site" listed there?

Comment: It is ok for me. I just restart Intellij